# ASP JavaScript - CheckBoxList - Capture selected value to Label.Text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need some help.I have a checkboxlist below.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label107" runat="server" Text="General Patient Teaching Methods Used/Information Given (Check all that apply)" CssClass="rdbBlock"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList6" runat="server" CssClass="rdbBlock">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Patient/Caregiver observed</span>" Value="Patient/Caregiver observed"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Disease process</span>" Value="Disease process"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Nursing visit frequecy</span>" Value="ursing visit frequecy"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Supply management</span<" Value="Supply management"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Emergency Procedures</span>" Value="Emergency Procedures"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>24 phone number</span>" Value="24 phone number"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Right/Responsibility</span>" Value="Right/Responsibility"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style=font-weight:normal;>Reviewed infusion admission packet</span>" Value="Reviewed infusion admission packet"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

What I want to do is grab the values from the selected ListItems and set the values to a label. I want to use JavaScript/JQuery, but I can't figure it out.

Here is what I use on TextBoxes and it works, but textboxes don't have multiple selection items to collect.

> YES - VERY IMPORTANT - NO POST BACK!!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                        function setLabelText9(e) {
                                            e.preventDefault();  // To prevent postback
                                            var txtValue = $('#<%=txtCaregiverHelper.ClientID%>').val();
                                            $('#<%=Label286.ClientID%>').html(txtValue);
                                        }
                                        function getLabelText9(e) {
                                            e.preventDefault(); // To prevent postback
                                            alert($('#<%=Label286.ClientID%>').html());
                                        }
                                    </script>
```

Desired result:
If CheckBoxList ListItem (using index) 0, 3, 5 are checked, set label to selected value from index 0, 3, 5. I can concat some values together so it looks right with spaces and punctuation. I just need the help on the javascript/jquery code to collect all the values and store them in the label text.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setLabelText9() method should be changed following way to read multiple selected value.

```
        var indexes = []; 
        $('#<%=txtCaregiverHelper.ClientID%> :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
          indexes[i] = $(selected).val(); 
        });
        $('#<%=Label286.ClientID%>').html(indexes.join(" "));
```